# Function calls with constants optimization in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, optimization, compiler-construction

If you have function call with constants, it has no side effects and it is not dependent on anything, like the following:

```
int foo(int a,int b)
{         
  return a+b;   
}
```

Does the function get inlined? Or, perhaps is the function evaluated at compile-time, with the result of this evaluation inserted in place of the function call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried compiling this using a fairly old gcc -

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
} 


int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(100, 123) ;
}
```

And main compiled to this -

```
LFB1439:
    subq    $8, %rsp
.LCFI1:
    movl    $223, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

So it compiled the addition at compile time getting 223.

Obviously the results depend on your code and compiler but this shows that it can and does both inline and compute the addition at compile time if it can.

Comment: So then is there any use in constexpr ?

Comment: Any such optimization is heavily dependent on the compiler and the complexity of the function. `constexpr` is used to ensure the compiler does what you want if a function is too complex, or a compiler is too naive.

Comment: what optimization flags did you use?

Comment: @coredump - `constexpr` tells the compiler that the thing it applies to can be used in a context that **requires** a compile-time constant. If it wasn't marked `constexpr`, such usage would be illegal.

Comment: And yes absolutely @ronalchn all this does it answer the question *can* the compiler inline and precalculate this. It absolutely does not say that it *will* in any given case.

Comment: I tried the above with -O1 in gcc 4.7.1, and the function is then called (movl $123, %esi // movl $100, $edi // call __Z3foooii). With -O2 and above it's optimised out.

Answer (score 4):

Not in C++. They will not be executed at compile time just like that - unless the compiler magically does it. However, this cannot be forced.

However, with C++11, you can use `constexpr` to ensure it is evaluated at compile time, eg:

```
constexpr int get_five() {return 5;}
```

Thus, you can rewrite your function as:

```
constexpr int foo(int a,int b)
{         
  return a+b;   
}
```

Note that you do not have to worry if the arguments to this function are not always constant.

From Wikipedia:

> If a constexpr function or constructor is called with arguments which
>   aren't constant expressions, the call behaves as if the function were
>   not constexpr, and the resulting value is not a constant expression.
>   Likewise, if the expression in the return statement of a constexpr
>   function does not evaluate to a constant expression for a particular
>   invocation, the result is not a constant expression.

This means that `foo(1,1)` will be constant, but:

```
int i,j;
cin >> i >> j;
foo(i,j) // this is not constant
```

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#constexpr_-_Generalized_constant_expressions

Comment: But what happens if you use constexpr when it cannot be evaluated on compile-time, or when it has side-effects ?

Comment: @coredump then don't use `constexpr`

Comment: @coredump Then you cannot use it as a constexpr and the compiler tells you. In the above example, `constexpr int x = foo(5,6);` would work, `constexpr int foo(runtimeVariable1, runtimeVariable2);` would not.

Comment: @coredump, the compiler will assume it can be evaluated at compile time (though it might throw an error when it finds it can't evaluate it). Only use `constexpr` when you know the function has no side-effects and doesn't get input data anywhere other than from its arguments.

Comment: @juanchopanza, `constexpr int foo(runtimeVariable1, runtimeVariable2);` will still compile correctly. It just won't be executed at compile time. The compiler will handle any non-constant arguments to a constant expression function correctly.

Comment: @ronalchn I don't think so. The compiler should complain about that, and mine (gcc 4.6.3) does.

Answer (score 2):

If you define that in the header file, then there's a great chance of it being inlined. If you're using integral compile-time constants as its arguments, then the compiler should be able to execute that function on compile-time.

Even though there is no such guarantee, you should trust your compiler. Their pretty good at optimizing your code. If you want to ensure that the function is executed on compile time, you can add a `constexpr` overload(C++11 only):

```
constexpr int foo(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

I've tried the following snippet:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    return add(5, 2);
}
```

When compiled using GCC and the -O3 flag, it gets compiled to this:

```
0x08048300 <+0>:    mov    $0x7,%eax
0x08048305 <+5>:    ret
```

Therefore, you can see that it is actually being executed on compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Whether such optimisations are performed are not a defined part of the C and C++ languages. Essentially, the compiler is free to optimise as it sees fit as long as the resulting code is valid according to the source. In the general case, at higher optimisation levels, this call could be either inlined or if the call sites always pass in constants (values known at compile time), the result can be calculated at compile time and any runtime overhead completely avoided.

The general cases under which case an optimising compiler will choose not to inline functions are:

- Recursive functions
- When it is favouring size over speed or if inlining would greatly skew the size of the end binary

One more issue to note is that inlining will change the linkage of a function.

Compiling the following C code on both GCC and G++ with `-O3`:

```
int foo(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

int main(void)
{
    return foo(1, 2);
}
```

Results in the following assembly code:

```
00000000004004e0 <main>:
main():
  4004e0:       b8 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%eax
  4004e5:       c3                      retq
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the assembly listing to see if it gets inlined, but as mentioned earlier, it is compiler specific.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler and on the optimization settings, but in general you can assume that any sufficiently advanced compiler will inline such a trivial function when you switch on at least a bit of optimization.

When you want to make sure that the function is inlined, you can always declare it with the inline keyword:

```
inline int foo(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

but such well-intended hints should generally be avoided, because most compilers are better at deciding which functions to inline than most programmers.

Comment: That doesn't ensure the function is inlined. It is a hint to the compiler and the compiler may chose to ignore the hint. The main use of inline is to allow you to put code in header files without producing linker errors.

Answer (score 0):

Possible scenario how this function can be calculated in compile time:
1) compiler inline `foo` function during one of inlining optimization phase.
2) during [constant propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding)  optimization phase compiler can "propagate" value of variables that are known in compile-time, i.e. constants and constant expression.

NB: You'll never know exactly whether the function is inlined until you see the assembler code  of your program. Even if you use `inline` specifier. Compiler may ignore this specifier or inline function without this specifier.